# Change date format from MM-DD-YYYY to YY-MM-DD using a regular expression?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

A file contains

```
03-01-2020 04-01-2021
03-02-2020 04-02-2021
03-03-2020 04-03-2021
03-04-2020 04-04-2021
03-05-2020 04-05-2021
03-06-2020 04-06-2021
03-07-2020 04-07-2021
03-08-2020 04-08-2021
03-09-2020 04-09-2021
03-10-2020 04-10-2021
03-11-2020 04-11-2021
03-12-2020 04-12-2021
03-13-2020 04-13-2021
```

***How will I change it to (using regular expression)***

```
20-03-01 21-04-01
20-03-02 21-04-02
20-03-03 21-04-03
20-03-04 21-04-04
20-03-05 21-04-05
20-03-06 21-04-06
20-03-07 21-04-07
20-03-08 21-04-08
20-03-09 21-04-09
20-03-10 21-04-10
20-03-11 21-04-11
20-03-12 21-04-12
20-03-13 21-04-13
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
s/^#\s\+\(.\{-}\):/  21-04-01 "\1":/
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to place some capture groups in the right place:

```
%s/\v(\d\d-\d\d)-\d\d(\d\d) (\d\d-\d\d)-\d\d(\d\d)/\2-\1 \4-\3/
```

1. `\v` : Enable very magic mode to avoid having to escape all the parens.
2. `(\d\d-\d\d)` : Capture the first month and day.
3. `-\d\d` : Match the dash and first two digits of the year but don't capture them.
4. `(\d\d)` : Capture the last two digits of the year.
5. : Match the space.
6. `(\d\d-\d\d)-\d\d(\d\d)` : Repeat the above for the second date.

Capture groups are inserted into the replacement using the `\N` notation. Just count from the left each left parens `(` and that tells you which number to use to bring that group over.

There are some variations of this, too. The above is verbose but it's probably the easiest way to see what's going on. Here's a shorter version:

```
%s/\v(\d\d-\d\d)-\d\d(\d\d)/\2-\1/g
```

Here we use `g`lobal flag to apply the pattern twice per line rather than double the pattern manually.

Comment: @BLACKHAT Please give some indication as to whether this solution works for you (and accept the answer if it does).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `strptime`/`strftime` to demonstrate expression substitution;

```
%s/[0-9-]\+/\=strftime('%y-%m-%d', strptime('%m-%d-%Y', submatch(0)))/g
```